# How to declare and change global variable in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can anyone tell how to declare and change global variables in objective c

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does your Objective-C singleton look like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single source file:

```
int myGlobal;
```

Header file:

```
extern int myGlobal;
```

Any file including the header:

```
myGlobal = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just the same way that you would in C. Are you having any particular problem?

Comment: in c if u want to change global variable u use ::variable to change the value of it. But such feature is not available in objective c

Comment: can u please tell me how to do it in objective c

Comment: that's C++.  in C there's no special syntax for globals.

Comment: In fact, even in C++, you only *need* to use the global scope resolution operator (::) to disambiguate from identifiers with the same name in the same (or closer) namespace.

Comment: @Muniraj: That looks like C++, not C. BTW: Please write "you" instead of "u", it hurts looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

On a related note; global variables are (very) generally speaking considered a Bad Thing™. In Obj-C the more common approach is making them a property on a singleton object, ensuring at least some encapsulation is taking place.

In an AppKit/UIKit application; a global variable might more properly be a property on your application delegate; another, somewhat more involved, option is making a singleton class for encapsulating the variable and related methods.

Answer (score 2):

**Global Variable for Complete iPhone Project**

For Declare/Define/Use a global variable follow these easy steps:-

1. Create a NSObject File with named "GlobalVars.h and .m" or as u wish
2. Declare your global variable in GlobalVars.h file after #import and before @implementation like-

   extern NSString *Var_name;
3. initialize it in GlobalVars.m file after #import and before @implementation like-

   NSString *Var_name = @"";
4. Define its property in AppDelegate.h File

   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Var_name;
5. synthesize it in AppDelegate.m File like-

   @synthesize Var_name;
6. Now where you want to use this variable (in .m file) just import/inclue GlobalVars.h file in that all .h files, and you can access or can changes easily this variable.
7. Carefully follow these Steps and it'll work Surely.