# How do I create a global variable using Objectvie-C in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, global-variables

I'm the beginner in iPhone software development, and I'm creating a HTTP request using the SOAP XML parsing method.

I was creating a variable `soapResult` for storing the received http data. I want to use the `soapResult` value into another class.

How can I access that value. I was going to make it a global variable but i don't know how to create and use it?

Also if that method is wrong then how should I implement it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872437/how-to-declare-and-change-global-variable-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, singletons are preferred over global variables.

I found this article useful on a similar matter: [Cocoa with Love: Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use something like Registry pattern. Just create class Registry with static methods and static properties. It is better way to controll all shared stuff in your app

Answer (score 0):

Global vars are not preferred in objective-c, but if you want to use, [this](http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2002-April/037869.html)
approach works well.